# get data from dynamically created controls in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform application that allows a user(customer) to place their order. In order to so,when the user clicks "place your order" `button` then another form is shown up, which includes a number of different controls (numericUpDown, TextBox, Combobox, Calendar and CheckBoxes). The user then has to fill all the fields and then confirm the process.

Now this scenario is just for placing a single order, what if want to allow the user to place a number of orders at once?

The scenario I want to apply is that the user firstly has to determine how many orders they want, then based on that number another form is created and filled by controls that are created dynamically according to the number of order specified.

I mean, the user wants 8 orders, so eight controls of each type is dynamically created.

Actually, till this point, I've managed to do so, but what I'm stuck on is that how could I get the data from the controls?

Back to my example:
If the customer wanted 8 orders, then I shall have:
8 textboxes
8 comboboxes
8 calendars
and so on

To be more clear, Now I want to get the inserted data from textbox1, calender1, combobox1 .... and so on, then store them in a temp list to be stored later into the database,

Anyone could give me a clue?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to make your own user control for each order (each line).
Pick Add->User control... in project context menu then enter control name "MyOrderControl" and put all your order's controls on it.

Also you will need to create spectial class to hold order's data (if ouy have no such class). And add to MyOrderControl special method to return filled instance of that class.

```
public partial class MyOrderControl : UserControl
{
    public MyOrderControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public Order GetFilledOrder()
    {
        //Validate data
        return new Order()
        {
            Name = textBox1.Text,
            Quantity = (int)numericUpDown1.Value
        };
    }
}
```

On form initialization you can create any amount of your control instances. You can use FlowLayoutPanel to place them automaticaly.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        const int nOrders = 10;
        for (int n = 0; n < nOrders; n++)
        {
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new MyOrderControl());
        }
    }
```

And then add spectial method to retrieve all filled orders (using System.Collections.Generic, System.Linq):

```
    public IEnumerable<MyOrderControl.Order> GetOrders()
    {
        foreach (var order in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<MyOrderControl>())
        {
            yield return order.GetFilledOrder();
        }
    }
```

It will allow you to access all orders from parent form:

```
    public void AcquireOrders()
    {
        var form = new Form1();
        if (form.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;

        foreach (var order in form.GetOrders())
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Order: {0} Qty={1}",
               order.Name, order.Quantity);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great!!. That is exactly what I was looking for. Great thanks for your answer